# Jooq extra-quoting function parameters in a custom routine

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have two routines defined in postgresql, which are `array_distinct(anyarray)` and `array_remove_all(anyarray, anyarray)`. This does get generated correctly in the `Routines` class from jooq.

Additional to this, I have some functions I use to generate some PostgreSQL array operators:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> Field<Array<T>>.concatenate(other: Array<T>) : Field<Array<T>> {
    return DSL.field("{0} || {1}", Array<T>::class.java, this, other)
}
```

This is in Kotlin, so the java equivalent would be something like:

```java
Field<Array<T>> concatenate(Field<Array<T>> a, Array<T> b, Class<T[]> type) {
    return DSL.field("{0} || {1}", type, a, b);
}
```

Now I am trying to write this query in jooq:

```sql
UPDATE users
    SET groups = array_distinct(
        array_remove_all(groups, ARRAY['a', 'b']) || ARRAY['c']
    );
```

For the sake of brevity, I am removing a couple of type-casts that are required to make this code valid.

However, when I do this:

```java
    DSL.update(USERS)
        .set(USERS.GROUPS, Routines.arrayDistinct(
            Routines.arrayRemoveAll(
                USERS.GROUPS,
                arrayOf("a", "b")
            )
            .asTypedField<Array<String>>()
            .concatenate(arrayOf("c"))
        ).asTypedField())
```

The `asTypedField` is something I need to do so that I can use `concatenate` as an extension function on `Field<Array<T>>`; internally it is nothing more than a type-cast.

The query that gets generated though is:

```sql
update "public"."users"
    set "public"."users"."groups" = "public"."array_distinct"('"public"."array_remove_all"(
        ''"public"."users"."groups"'', 
        ARRAY[''a'', ''b'']
    ) || ARRAY[''c'']'
)
```

This entire thing is just riddled with extra quote (`'`) marks everywhere. What do I need to do to generate the query that I mentioned above?

Even the final array in concatenate, has all of its elements using the quote `'` twice everywhere (`''a''`, `''b''`).

Answer (score 0):

The jOOQ code generator doesn't currently (as of version 3.10 and the upcoming 3.11) support the `anyarray` type in PostgreSQL. The pending feature request his here:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5479

You will need to apply any of these workarounds:

- Use plain SQL templating also for the `array_remove_all` function. You're already using plain SQL templating for the `||` operator, so this might be the preferred approach here. Especially, if you want the generic type safety of having the two array types be of the same type.
- Use a custom data type binding for the `array_remove_all` function: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings